# .next() is undefined in the Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through all my price spans then insert some HTML showing their savings.

I can get this to work on one product just fine as long as I remove the `.each` function and the `(this).next`.

The error I get in Firebug is `TypeError: jQuery(...).next(...).html(...) is undefined`

```
jQuery('.price').each(function(){

    var pricea = parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".count .amount:first").html().replace("£","")) ;
    var priceb = parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".count .amount:last").html().replace("£",""));
    var total = (pricea - priceb) / (pricea) * 100;
    var totalfixed = total.toFixed();
    jQuery(this).next('.saving').append(totalfixed);

    console.log(totalfixed);

});
```

My HTML:

```
<li class="product ">
  <span class="price">
    <del class="count"><span class="amount2">WAS</span><span class="amount">&pound;35</span></del>
    <ins class="count"><span class="amount2">NOW </span><span class="amount">&pound;20</span><span style="clear:both" class="saving"> <br><br> YOU SAVE %</span></ins> </span> 
</li>

<li class="product ">
  <span class="price">
    <del class="count"><span class="amount2">WAS</span><span class="amount">&pound;35</span></del>
    <ins class="count"><span class="amount2">NOW </span><span class="amount">&pound;20</span><span style="clear:both" class="saving"> <br><br> YOU SAVE %</span></ins> </span> 
</li>
```

You can view the live demo [Here](http://shared1.digibugnetwork.co.uk/~tiptopde/live/)

Comment: When I put the above code in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/biinjo/R4rjx/) I get a different error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined.

What jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put the above code in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/biinjo/R4rjx/) I get a different error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined.

This fixes your issue though:

```
jQuery('.price').each(function(){

    var pricea = parseInt(jQuery(this).find(".amount:first").html().replace("£","")) ;
    var priceb = parseInt(jQuery(this).find(".amount:last").html().replace("£",""));

    var total = (pricea - priceb) / (pricea) * 100;

    jQuery(this).next('.saving').append(total.toFixed());

});
```

`.find()` searches inside `jQuery(this)` for an element with class `.amount` (the :first and :last one)

Answer (score 1):

.next('.saving') is expecting to find a span tag with a class of saving right next to .price like so:

```
<span class="price"></span>
<span class="saving"></span> // <-- it is looking for this
```

But your code is like this:

```
<span class="price">
    <span class="saving"></span>
</span>
```

for your situation you will need

```
jQuery(this).find('.saving').append(totalfixed); //this will find .saving inside of .price
```

For the record I was only able to see this once I put the html in my editor that highlights open/close tags. Please format your code nicely not only for us but for yourself as well, it will save you quite a few headaches.